# How to plot different graph using plot_ly

Tags: r, plot, merge, plotly, candlestick-chart

I'm actually trying to plot two different graphs together.
Here we are with the code of the two different graphs.

PS: Here you can download both Excel
[here](https://ufile.io/0be4i)!

As first one, we have a ohlc graph, representing a time series:

```
df1 <- AA
plot_ly(x = df1, type="ohlc", open=df$Apertura, 
close=df$Ultimo, high=df$Massimo, low=df$Minimo)
```

[image]
Then we have a simple square, meaning 5 consecutive points connected with lines:

```
df2 <- bb
plot(df2, type="b")
```

EDIT3: You can also plot using plot_ly. Behind there is the code:

```
df2 <- bb
p2 <- plot_ly(df2,x=~Data,y=~Price, mode = ' lines+markes')
subplot(p2, p1, nrows = 2, margin = 0.15)
```

[image]
So, I actually need to represent the square graph, second one, over the time series chart.

EDIT1: Pay Attention, i need the two graph in the SAME graph. If you notice, i have taken 4 points for plotting the second graph THAT ARE INCLUDED in the time series. I need to see the square, correctly sized, in the ohlc graph.

EDIT2: This is the result that i would like to achieve (i have done it manually)
[image]

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: is it possible to plot the second plot as `plot_ly` too?

Comment: how do you connect 5 points using plotly?